# Why the two ways to get blockhash is not same?

Tags: polkadot, json-rpc

why the two ways to get `blockhash` is not same ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because your chain is producing blocks now.

I think you can get the same result by specifying the block number.

This RPC is always get the latest block if you didn't specify the block number.

Comment: Can you update your question? How to reproduce this?

Comment: oh, this problem solve

Comment: @Rose if this was the answer to your question, you can mark it as the solution. Otherwise, please post the answer to your problem yourself.